# Retrieve by inserting ORDER of Merged table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a 3 tables such as "BASE_Customer", "BASE_Invoice" and "BASE_Payment" the below structure,

[image]

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_Customer
(
    CustomerId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CustomerName VARCHAR(45)
    PRIMARY KEY(CustomerId)
)
INSERT INTO BASE_Customer (CustomerName) VAlUES ('LEE')

CREATE TABLE BASE_Invoice
(
    InvoiceId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    InvoiceDate DATE,
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    InvoiceMethod VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, -- CASH or CREDIT
    Amount MONEY,
    PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceId)
)
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-16', 1, 'CASH', 1000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-16', 1, 'CREDIT', 2000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-17', 1, 'CREDIT', 500);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-18', 1, 'CREDIT', 2000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-18', 1, 'CASH', 150);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-19', 1, 'CREDIT', 1000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-19', 1, 'CREDIT', 3000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-19', 1, 'CASH', 1000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Invoice (InvoiceDate, CustomerId, InvoiceMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-20', 1, 'CREDIT', 2250);

CREATE TABLE BASE_Payment
(
    PaymentId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    PaymentDate DATE,
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    InvoiceId INT NULL,
    PaymentMethod VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, -- CASH or CREDIT, ADVANCE
    Amount MONEY,
    PRIMARY KEY(PaymentId)
)
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, InvoiceId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-16', 1, 1, 'CASH', 1000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-16', 1, 'CREDIT', 500);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, InvoiceId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-18', 1, 4, 'ADVANCE', 500);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-18', 1, 'CREDIT', 2000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, InvoiceId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-18', 1, 5, 'CASH', 150);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-18', 1, 'CREDIT', 5000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-19', 1, 'CREDIT', 1200);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, InvoiceId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-19', 1, 7, 'ADVANCE', 500)
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, InvoiceId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-19', 1, 8, 'CASH', 1000);
INSERT INTO BASE_Payment (PaymentDate, CustomerId, InvoiceId, PaymentMethod, Amount) VAlUES ('2020-01-20', 1, 9, 'ADVANCE', 750);
```

- Customer table should Join to both tables "BASE_Invoice" and "BASE_Payment" (CustomerId is Foreign Key on both tables)
- when inserting a data into "BASE_Invoice" table if invoice method column CASH at the time Invoice Payment inserting with payment method CASH,
- when inserting a data into "BASE_Invoice" table if invoice method column CREDIT some times we insert payment with payment method ADVANCE or otherwise we don't insert payment on payment table.
- on payment table only can insert CREDIT payment methods

I need to merge all the tables once and retrieve the ORDER of output such as below screen shot,

[image]

The issue is how to merge tables and get the Order of transaction

Answer (score 3):

Databases do not store data "in order" (for the most part).

If you want data out in a specific order, you *must* supply an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.

---

In your data model:

- `BASE_Invoice` **is a** transaction.
- `BASE_Payment` **is a** transaction.

You're missing a table that holds the information for a transaction.  That table will include all columns common to both types of transactions, a transaction ID (PK) for all types of transactions, and information about the transaction that can be used by the `ORDER BY` clause.

It some cases, the Transaction ID *could* be used to determine `ORDER BY`.  In other cases, you may need to include a timestamp column to be used by the `ORDER BY` clause.